# Moderator Election, Inbox Notifications, Display Numbers, And You

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, election, global-inbox

While I was replying to some comments in the 2013 Moderator election, I noticed something weird in my inbox:

[image: 14 comments in one nomination]

So, when you look at the post which is linked there, you see only 4-5 comments:

[image: oh no there isn't]

I *think* that SO is improperly using the number of comments addressed towards you in the 'parent post' (which in this case is the community mod post), but giving it either the wrong title or wrong display count.

Comment: Weird, I can't reproduce (and I'm the *owner* of said post). I see it just fine ("a comment" or "3 comments").

Comment: @MadaraUchiha if you haven't gotten replies on other posts in the election, then it doesn't add to the count, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next deploy will fix this roll up bug.

Effectively we were choosing "nothing" as a legitimate grouping for all nomination comments, causing all comments on all nominations on all elections to be grouped ... which was wrong.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for fixing this :)